# 2D vector using struct

Tags: c++, vector

So I have the following code where I read an XML file and save the values to a vector. I don't have much experience with vectors, but now that I have my parameter "motor", I want to be able to go to a motor value, and read the parameters from that vector.

Would I have to add something to my struct? Or intialize a 2D vector `vector<vector <NameValue>> motors;` If I do initialize a 2D vector, how would I be able to populate the vector. Or is there a good guide that can help me fully understand vectors?

Here is the documentation for TinyXML. http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <tinyxml.h>

using namespace std; 

struct NameValue
{
    string motor;
    string name;
    string value;
};

vector<NameValue> read()
{   //READING XML FILE
    QString directory;
    string file;
    directory = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
    file = directory.toUtf8().constData();
    file = file + "/Profile.xml";
    cout<<file<<endl;
    TiXmlDocument doc (file);
    if(!doc.LoadFile()){
        cout<<"Cannot open file"<<endl;}

    vector<NameValue> xmlread;
    NameValue elem;

    TiXmlElement *pRoot, *pParm, *pMotor;
    pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement("PRO");
    if (pRoot) //parsing
    {
     pMotor = pRoot->FirstChildElement("Motor");
      if(pMotor){
        while (pMotor)
        {
            elem.motor = pMotor->Attribute("value");
            pParm = pMotor->FirstChildElement("PARAMETER");
            while (pParm)
            {
                elem.name = pParm->Attribute("name");
                elem.value = pParm->Attribute("value");
                xmlread.push_back(elem);
                pParm = pParm->NextSiblingElement("PARAMETER");
            }
            pMotor = pMotor->NextSiblingElement("Motor");

        }
   }
}
   return xmlread;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   vector<NameValue> elems = read();
   cout<<elems[0].motor<<endl;

}
```

Here is a snip of my XML File:

```
<PRO>
   <Motor value = "1">
         <PARAMETER name = "SPEED" value = "100" />
         <PARAMETER name = "LOOP" value = "1" />
         <PARAMETER name = "DEADBAND" value = "10" />
   </Motor>
   <Motor value = "2">
         <PARAMETER name = "SPEED" value = "100" />
         <PARAMETER name = "LOOP" value = "1" />
         <PARAMETER name = "DEADBAND" value = "10" />
   </Motor>
   <Motor value = "3">
         <PARAMETER name = "SPEED" value = "100" />
         <PARAMETER name = "LOOP" value = "1" />
         <PARAMETER name = "DEADBAND" value = "10" />
   </Motor>
</PRO>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a small sample of your xml file?

Comment: ok, sorry about that.

Comment: What is this library `#include <tinyxml.h>`? If it's an external library with a public API, you need to at least give us the documentation for it.

Comment: sorry again :( There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you already have needs very little modification in order to produce a 2D vector. Simply use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to construct inner vectors in-place:

```
vector<vector<NameValue>> xmlread2D;
NameValue elem;

TiXmlElement *pRoot, *pParm, *pMotor;
pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement("PRO");
if (pRoot)
{
    pMotor = pRoot->FirstChildElement("Motor");
    while (pMotor)
    {
        // allocate new inner vector
        xmlread2D.emplace_back();
        auto& xmlread = xmlread2D.back();
        // in C++17 the above can be replaced with a single line

        // unmodified inner loop
        elem.motor = pMotor->Attribute("value");
        pParm = pMotor->FirstChildElement("PARAMETER");
        while (pParm)
        {
            elem.name = pParm->Attribute("name");
            elem.value = pParm->Attribute("value");
            xmlread.push_back(elem);
            pParm = pParm->NextSiblingElement("PARAMETER");
        }
        pMotor = pMotor->NextSiblingElement("Motor");
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do I access the parameters and such?
In my previous code, I would use elems[0].motor or elems[0].value and so forth. How would I be able to index these values using this way?

Comment: @miceandmon just use two indices as if it were a 2D array, e.g. `elems[0][0].motor`.

Comment: I actually got quite a bit of errors.
`class std::vector<std::vector<NameValue> >' has no member named 'emplace_back'`
`ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'xmlread' with no type`
`invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'std::vector<NameValue>'
`request for member 'push_back" in 'smlread', which is of non-class type 'int'`

First I'd have to change my return type of the functinon to a double vector. As for the emplace_back errors, no clue. I'm not using C++11

Comment: I'm using QT 5.5.1 and using  g++ compiler

Comment: @miceandmon I see you're not using C++11 - is there a particular reason? If so  I can modify my answer; otherwise I strongly recommend it.

Comment: Got it. Added CONFIG += c++11 to my .pro file on QT.
It compiled this time. but when I write in my main:
`vector<vector<NameValue> > elems = read();
cout<<elems[0][1].value<<endl;`
I get nothing.
Keep in mind that I did change my return value in read to be xmlread2D

Comment: yes. Other than the face that I changed my return values to `vector<vector<NameValue> >'
I `cout<<elems.value<<endl;` inside the loop and it display the correct values.
When I add `xmlread2D.push_back(xmlread);` after the `pMotor = pMotor->NextSiblingElement("Motor")` I still get nothing. I would assume that it adds the xmlread vector to xmlread2D. Am I wrong?

Comment: I started debugging and when I try to `cout<<xmlread[0]<<endl;` it gives me 'no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' `
It looks like it's not adding the elements to the xmlread vector?

Comment: @miceandmon `xmlread[0]` is of type `NameValue`, which doesn't have an [*insertion operator*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) overload for `cout`. Do something like `xmlread[0].name` instead, which is of type `string` and does have an overload (alternatively use a debugger + breakpoint).

Comment: You're right. I just tested it with different parameter values, and it looks like it's only outputting the data out for motor 1....

Comment: @miceandmon DAMN I just realized my mistake - the initialization should be inside the outer loop. My apologies! I'll edit the answer.

Comment: any other suggestions? I'm running out of things to try

Comment: You're a freaking genius! That worked! :,D
Thanks for sticking through.

Comment: @miceandmon no problem; and again apologies for wasting so much of your time with a stupid mistake like that...